# Scalalogging will not work in sbt playproject with logging to stdout

Tags: scala, playframework, slf4j, logback

My sbt is setup based on this great answer: [Confused how to setup a multi project sbt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188771/confused-how-to-setup-a-multi-project-sbt-project)

So in the `Dependencies.scala` have added:

```
val scalaLogging = "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % scalaLoggingVersion
//val logbackCore = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % logbackVersion
val logbackClassic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion
```

(Have commented out `logbackCore` - Do I even need that?)

Have added `scalaLogging` and `logbackClassic` to  commonDependencies (other libs removed):

```
val commonDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    scalaLogging,
    //slf4j,
    //logbackCore,
    logbackClassic
)
```

Also in the `/services` sbt module , added this to a `UserServiceImpl` class:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging
class UserServiceImpl (.....) extends SecurityService with LazyLogging {

    def show(.....) {
        logger.trace("UserService.show called")
        logger.debug("UserService.show called")
    }
}
```

Also, in  /services/resources ,  added `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%logger:%line - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Now when my play app is launched , log is not seen  when `sbt run`, regular play logs are just fine that I put in my controllers etc.

For good measure , have also dropped a `logback.xml` in the `/conf` folder, but still no output.

**I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, hoping someone can clarify things for me.**

Note:  I am using sbt to compile my project, but I make edits in IntelliJ and for some reason IntelliJ doesn't not pickup scala-logging correctly.  My import is highlighted in red, my LazyLogging trait keyword that I am using on my UserService 'with LazyLogging' is in red.   Also my actual log statements like logger.debug the word 'logger' is red.  It doesnt' seem to resolve these, yet sbt compiles it fine.

Comment: Blankman have you tried putting logback.xml into src/main/resources ? Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149798/akka-slf4j-logback-configuration-and-usage/20571679#20571679

Comment: No, I don't have a src/main/resources.  I did try /services/src/main/resources and /play-web/conf/

Comment: What values are you using for logbackVersion and scalaLoggingVersion?

Comment: @drstevens logback is 1.1.2 and scalaLogging is 2.1.2

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you explicitly add `commonDependencies` to dependencies of all sub-projects in question opposed to inheriting them through `dependsOn`? Make sure to always be regenerating intellij project from sbt. Additionally, I've noticed that project does not get generated correctly if code does not build via sbt.

Comment: @drstevens I use sbt for my builds and running the play app, I just use intellij for coding.

Comment: right, what happens if you try and build in sbt after making the change I suggested? Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @drstevens I added scalaLogging and logbackClass explicitly to my commonDependencies, serviceDependencies and webDependencies and I still see no trace/debug messages.

Comment: @Blankman Have you tried editing `application.conf` and commenting out all logger settings: `logger.rot`, `logger.play`, `logger.application`, and then placing **`application-logger.xml`** (the name is important) in your `/conf` directory (or any directory that is shown when you execute `show resourceDirectories`? IMHO when you think of it, you'd like to configure it globally anyway for the whole application, and not module by module.

Comment: @lpiepiora ok that worked! I now have the same logging as before.  if you want, you can move this to an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: @Blankman I think you should be using a name derived from your package name and class name. LazyLogging defines a logger as `Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName))`, so I guess your logger's name should be the package or the full qualified class name. If you don't use package then the class name, e.g. `UserServiceImpl`

Comment: @lpiepiora thanks I figured that out.  Please put your answer in a proper answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Blankman thanks! I've done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the logback working, you have to edit the `application.conf` and comment out all logger settings: `logger.root`, `logger.play`, `logger.application`, etc.

Then place a logback configuration in a file called **`application-logger.xml`** (the name is important) in your `/conf` directory.